# How to get asp.net gridview entire cell values inside html textbox onchange="return Calculations(this);" jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to inside gridview html textbox values enter, when it loses focus(mean jQuery `onchange="return fuction()"`) side I would like to know which row of the table it is in. Mean that entire cell values detail required any idea ?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adjusting time(HH:MM:SS)">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="txtHours" runat="server" type="text" 
                       class="form-control" placeholder="HH"
                       onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event);"
                       onchange="return Calculations(this);" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="txtMinutes" runat="server" type="text"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="MM"
                       onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event);"  
                       onchange="return Calculations(this);" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adjusting time(HH:MM:SS)"><ItemTemplate><div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HH" onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event);" runat="server" id="txtHours" onchange="return Calculations(this);" /></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event);" runat="server" id="txtMinutes" onchange="return Calculations(this);" /></div><div class="col-md-3"> </div></div></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField> like more html texboxs there and jqery side get grid val

Comment: not here, in your question please

Comment: @ Poonam did u get any idea what is my problem , and what im expected
above code gridview side TemplateField and onchange="return Calculations(this);" im writing jquery related code for get that cell values

Comment: that's why I'm asking for your code na

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
function Calculations(elem) {
    var TabChangeId = $(elem).attr("id");
    if (TabChangeId == "txtHours") {
        var CurrentNode = $(elem).parent().parent().parent().parent();
        var EmpName = CurrentNode.find('#lblEmployeename').text();
    }
}
```

Clicking on hours or minutes and seconds will get values that row.